# How to set initial state in React to display nothing before fetching data on demand?

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to display data fetched from API. The API url is based on user input. Once a user inputs and clicks submit, it is supposed to display the fetched data. But before user click submit, it should display nothing.

The problem I have is, when rendering the a user's data in lists in html, the map function doesn't exist on property{}, before user input anything. What should i set as the initial state?

The transformedData works fine. `console.log(transformedData)` prints

[image: datastructure]

I'd like to display every title as a list. Example user input can be `0x147412d494731cbb91dbb5d7019464a536de04dc`

```
import { useState } from "react";

// example user:  0x147412d494731cbb91dbb5d7019464a536de04dc

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [enteredWallet, setEnteredWallet] = useState("");
  const [owner, setOwner] = useState("");

  const walletChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredWallet(event.target.value);
  };

  const submittedHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setOwner(enteredWallet);
    fetchNFTHandler();
  };

  function fetchNFTHandler() {
    fetch(
      `https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?owner=${owner}&order_direction=desc&offset=0&limit=10`
    )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const transformedData = data.assets.map((element, index) => {
          return {
            title: element.name,
            id: index,
          };
        });
        setData(transformedData);
        console.log(transformedData);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h3>Show me assets in this wallet</h3>
        <form onSubmit={submittedHandler}>
          <input
            placeholder="wallet address"
            value={enteredWallet}
            onChange={walletChangeHandler}
          />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <div> 
          console.log(data)
          {/* {data.map((element) => (<li key={element.id}> 
 {element.title}</li>))}
 */}. 
{/* here is the problem. before user input, this map function doesn't work */}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Firstly, be specific in the issue(s) when posting a question, rather than saying it "doesn't work". Secondly, your initial value for data is an empty object. Objects don't have a `.map` function. You should set it to an empty array initially: `const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

Comment: I modified the question to state the exact error message

Comment: thanks. it's fixed